# Poisson Process problem, transform the possibility notation

Tags: probability

Question: Suppose that a store opens at 0 pm and customers arrive according to a non-homogeneous poisson process ${N(t),t\ge0}$ with the intensity function $\lambda(t)=2t+1$ per hour.
Let $S_3$ denote the time at which the third customer arrives. Calculate $P\{S_3 \ge 4|N(2)=1\}$.

This means the conditional possibility of the 3rd customer arrives at or after time 4, under the condition of the customer arrive at time 2 is 1.

If the question is $P\{S_3 \gt 4|N(2)=1\}$, implies the possibility of the number of customers arrive between time 2 and 4 is 1. But for this particular question, I don't know how to do it since I don't know how to calculate the possibility of the 3rd customer arrive exactly at time 4. Maybe I did it wrong at very first step. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a customer arrives at exactly time $t$ is zero. Recall that the integral of a continuous function over e.g. $(a,b)$ is the same as the integral over $(a,b]$. We want to find the probability that there are less than two arrivals in the inte interval $(2,4)$. Let $\Lambda_{s,t}=\int_s^t\lambda(u)\mathsf du$ be the expected number of arrivals between times $s$ and $t$. Then

$$
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb P\{N(4) = 1|N(2)=1 \} +\mathbb P\{N(4) = 2|N(2)=1\}\\ =&
\mathbb P\{N(4) - N(2) = 0 \} + \mathbb P\{N(4)-N(2)=1\}\\
=& \frac{e^{-\Lambda_{2,4}}\Lambda_{2,4}^0}{0!} + \frac{e^{-\Lambda_{2,4}}\Lambda_{2,4}^1}{1!}\\
=& e^{-14} + 14e^{-14}\\
=& 15e^{-14}.
\end{align*}
 $$